# How to adjust the Gamma of image using PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

How to adjust gamma of an image like [this](https://pinetools.com/adjust-gamma-image) website is doing, when I used the PHP filters llike gamma Correct and ImageMagick filter gammaImage, both give me brighten result, where as gamma value should give a darken effect to image.
So, how to adjust the gamma of image USING php like this website is performing the gamma function?

Code for Adjusting Gamma of image:(just posted as to complete the answer)
before posting question here I was giving gamma value of greater than 10 with the aame code.

fCode for Adjusting Gamma of image:(just posted as to complete the answer)

```
     function gammaImage($imagePath, $gamma) {
     $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
      $imagick->gammaImage($gamma);
       header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
        echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
       }
       echo gammaImage($path,0.5);unction
```

Comment: Do you have to use PHP for this? You could use CSS filters.

Comment: I think that site is doing it wrong. But never mind, just choose a gamma value lower than 1.0 and you will get the darken effect.

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing what you've tried. Please update the question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please upvote my question I have added the code in the answer please ..

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, and I don't see a reason to upvote it either. Begging for votes rarely works on SO. One tip: The code for adjusting the gamma should be part of your question, not an answer.

Comment: @kiko software edited the question

Answer (score 2):

Some tools use the inverse of gamma (from what is done in ImageMagick). So try inverting your gamma value for use in ImageMagick from what you used in your other tool. For example to make it darker in ImageMagick, if you used 2 in your other tool, then try 1/2=0.5 in ImageMagick/Imagick.

In ImageMagick a value > 1 will make it brighter and a value of < 1 will make it darker.

Input:

[image]

```
convert lena.jpg -gamma 2 lena_g2.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert lena.jpg -gamma 0.5 lena_g0p5.jpg
```

[image]

So to make it darker in Imagick, use gamma value < 1, for example 0.5.

```
Imagick::gammaImage (0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code for Adjusting Gamma of image:(just posted as to complete the answer)

```
function gammaImage($imagePath, $gamma) {
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
    $imagick->gammaImage($gamma);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
   echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}
echo gammaImage($path,0.5);
```